# How I create cloud firestore index? flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Hello everyone I want to create cloud firestore index to my firestore project and I don't know what stream should I upload to index field because I got error in the app that say:

```
W/Firestore(17047): (24.0.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(chatRooms where participants.null == true order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
W/Firestore(17047): (24.0.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(users/2e5yO3ZYKDWprC8dVi1bzlY9a0Q2 order by __name__);
```

And this is my streams:

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await _fireStore
        .collection("chatRooms")
        .where("participants.${userModel.uid}", isEqualTo: true)
        .where("participants.${targetUser.uid}", isEqualTo: true)
        .get();
```

```
StreamBuilder(
                    stream: _fireStore
                        .collection('chatRooms')
                        .doc(chatRoom.chatRoomId)
                        .collection('messages')
                        .orderBy('createdon', descending: true)
                        .snapshots(),
```

I can't post image because need at least 10 reputation

Rules:

[Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw0Be.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use the error message that includes a direct link to create the missing index in the Firebase console.

As explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#create_a_missing_index_through_an_error_message) in the doc, "If you attempt a compound query with a range clause that doesn't map to an existing index, you receive an error".

So, catch the error in your code (normally with `if (snapshot.hasError)`, see [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes) in the FlutterFire doc), get the message and open the link in your preferred browser (with being logged to your Firebase project).

---

Other solutions are listed in the doc page referred to above, but again, with the link in the error message it's really easy!

Comment: Thank you so much @Renaud Tarnec

Comment: Is there any way to get the JSON for the firestore.indexes.json from that error message? Using the error message to create it manually AFTER it has failed is blatantly against infrastructure as code principles .... This is good to figure it out in dev mode but in production it should be deployed like the rules and functions.

Comment: Yes, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77379656/3371862) to your question.