# Get code for firestore.indexes.json from Firebase console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

If a Firestore query requires an index that does not exist, it will fail. The error message in the Logs Explorer contains a link that allows to trigger the creation of that index. That is a nice feature to figure it out in dev, but certainly not the way to deploy indexes to prod.

Unfortunately there seems to be no way to get the relevant code for `firestore.indexes.json` from that error message or to export it from the Firebase Console after it has been created from that link.

Do I miss anything out?

Example:

The query (in a Cloud Function) is:

```js
const docRefsMemberships = admin.firestore()
  .collectionGroup("members")
  .where("userId", "==", context.params.userId)
```

The error message in the Logs Explorer says:

> The query requires a COLLECTION_GROUP_ASC index for collection members and field userId

I used the keywords in the error message to build the following `firestore.indexes.json`:

```json
{
  "indexes": [
    {
      "collectionGroup": "members",
      "queryScope": "COLLECTION_GROUP",
      "fields": [
        { "fieldPath": "userId", "order": "ASCENDING" }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "fieldOverrides": []
}
```

There's nothing else in the file yet.

During deployment with firebase cli, I get the following error:

> Error: HTTP Error: 400, this index is not necessary, configure using single field index controls

According to the Firestore docs on [automatic indexing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#automatic_indexing), single-field indexes for collection groups (which is the case here) are not being maintained automatically, but there's no further information on how to create them.

So how do I get from the initial error message in the Logs Explorer (or the query) to the index configuration I need?

Answer (score 2):

> Unfortunately there seems to be no way to get the relevant code for
> firestore.indexes.json from that error message or to export it from
> the Firebase Console after it has been created from that link.

By running the `firebase firestore:indexes` CLI [command](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#firestore-commands), the indexes will be printed in the terminal and you will be able to copy them in order to manually update the `firestore.indexes.json` file.

Comment: Hey @Fred, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @renaud-tarnec . No, I did not have the time to look at it yet but I suppose it works as you cite the CLI docs. But why is this not even cross-linked in the indexing docs? Why doesn't it show up when I google it? It's the f*ckn same company, they should know SEO! I like the idea of Firebase, but the more I use it, the more I dislike it for their underwhelming effort to make it actually usable.